# Roxygenize error when documenting package ("$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors")

Tags: r

I was previously able to successfully build this package and it passed all checks when I called `devtools::check()` with no warnings/notes. I've just added some new functions and updated the documentation, and now when I try to run `devtools::document(roclets=c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace'))` I get the following error: 'Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors'.

I've attempted to use roxygen2::roxygenize and locate any stray "$"s in my code but have had no luck. I'm unsure where I could be using the $ operator that could be causing this problem.

I have found that the error comes from the "rd" generation stage of the roxygenize command, as when I run `devtools::document(roclets=c('collate', 'namespace'))` I get a different set of errors. In this case I get a long series of warnings for each tag in each of my R files along the lines of "Warning: @tag [row#x]: unknown tag".

When I run `traceback()` after running `devtools::document(roclets=c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace'))` I get the following:

```
16: paste0("@", x$tag, if (x$file != "") paste0(" [", x$file, "#", 
        x$line, "]"), ": ", message)
15: make_tag_message(x, paste0(...))
14: warning(make_tag_message(x, paste0(...)), call. = FALSE, immediate. = TRUE)
13: roxy_tag_warning("should have only a single argument")
12: registry[[x$tag]](x)
11: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
10: lapply(tokens, parse_tag, registry = registry)
9: vapply(x, is.null, logical(1))
8: compact(lapply(tokens, parse_tag, registry = registry))
7: parse_tags(tokens, registry = registry, global_options = global_options)
6: .f(call = .l[[1L]][[1L]], srcref = .l[[2L]][[1L]], tokens = .l[[3L]][[1L]], 
       ...)
5: purrr::pmap(list(call = as.list(parsed)[has_tokens], srcref = refs[has_tokens], 
       tokens = tokens[has_tokens]), block_create, registry = registry, 
       global_options = global_options)
4: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
3: lapply(files, tokenize_file, registry = registry, global_options = global_options)
2: parse_package(base_path, env = NULL, registry = registry, global_options = options)
1: roxygen2::roxygenize("D:\\Transposon_Work\\packFinder")
```

I'm unsure how including further documentation and adding functions have introduced this error, since I've searched through the whole document for each "$" operator I've used. I thought the issue might be something to do with my .Rbuildignore file which is automatically generated each time I run roxygenize to be as follows:
    ^.*.Rproj$
    ^.Rproj.user$

My github can be found here: https://github.com/jackgisby/Transposon_Search
Additionally, my local copy has the following:
- .git folder
- .gitignore folder
- .Rproj.user
- .Rhistory
These are not in .Rbuildignore.

Comment: It isn't obvious in your question or the package commit history when the problem started. Can you tell us which commit either (a) started the problem, or lacking that (b) which commit was your last-known "good"?

Comment: @r2evans I wasn't entirely sure when the problem started as I hadn't tried to update my documentation for a few days - the package was installing correctly and so I didn't notice the issue until now. I believe the last working commit was 4 days ago and since then I've added lots of documentation to my functions (which is what I think started the problem) and some additional functions. I've narrowed down the issue below, but I'm unsure why it's a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of trial and error I discovered that deleting the R files that documented my data in data/ allowed me to call `devtools::document(roclets=c('collate', 'namespace'))` without the error. After investigating further I realised that deleting the tag `@docType data` from each of these files also fixed the error. I am, however, unsure why this is causing a problem as previously I was able to document these functions with this tag - although I've added to the documentation since then.

The files with these tags removed are as follows:

- https://github.com/jackgisby/Transposon_Search/blob/development/R/packMatches.R
- https://github.com/jackgisby/Transposon_Search/blob/development/R/arabidopsisThalianaRefseqSubset.R

To conclude, the issue was fixed by deleting the roxygen `@docType data` tags for my documentation of my Rdata, but I'm unsure why this is the case.